# NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate generates errors with UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I've recently been working on a simple iOS application that uses a NSURLSessionDownloadTask to download an image from a web server. The download task executes perfectly, but dealing with the received image has proved to be a little odd. It seems as though the image is nil, although the session didn't return any errors and the `URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL)` delegate method is called. The app then crashes giving the typical `'fatal error: found nil when unwrapping an optional value'` on the line `var image: UIImage = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: location)!)!`. Any ideas?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: .Fade)

        let filePath: NSString = NSString(string: "https://www.codekaufman.com/screen.png")

        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: .defaultSessionConfiguration(), delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
        let downloadTask = session.downloadTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: filePath)!)

        downloadTask.resume()
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: .Fade)
    }

    // MARK: Download Delegate Funcions

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didResumeAtOffset fileOffset: Int64, expectedTotalBytes: Int64) {

    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
        println("\(totalBytesWritten) / \(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)")
    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            if UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: location)!) != nil {
                var image: UIImage = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: location)!)!
                self.imageView.image = image
            } else {
                println("Image was nil.")
            }
        })
        println("Finished download task.")
    }

}
```

Comment: The didFinishDownloadingToURL will get called regardless whether the download is successful for failure.  Check to see if the image is not nil.

Comment: I've updated it to check if the image is not nil, it still fails on the same line. @user523234

Comment: Try var image:UIImage? = .... (The addition of the question mark)

Comment: Still the same error @user523234

Comment: I have the same problem as you. The downloaded file has 0kb